# RestTemplate consuming Json string

Tags: java, resttemplate

I'm trying to consume a service returning a json String with content-type `application/json`, with Spring RestTemplate.

The response looks like this:

```
============================response begin==========================================
response: 200 OK
Headers
    Content-Length  : 108
    Content-Type    : application/json; charset=utf-8
Response Body : "a string with double quotes, JSON valid"
=======================response end=================================================
```

Now, when I'm using:

```
String result = template.postForObject("http://...", request, String.class)
```

result always contains `"\"a string with double quotes, Json valid\""`, whereas I would like to receive it escaped, `"a string with double quotes, Json valid"`.

I would also like to receive this answer without having to parse it.

It seems quite a trivial problem to me, but I haven't found any SO question or other resources on the web.

Comment: are you sure, that service response is not faulty here?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, Basically I'm receiving "a string" with double quotes. But it is Json valid in the end. It's worth investigating though, I'll have a look.

Comment: Is you API returning a json but wrapped in double quotes, essentially just a string.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like specifying `String.class` will give you the whole body as a String, without any form of deserialization (even if `application/json` is used, and even if a String is actually a valid form of JSON). This is because a `StringHttpMessageConverter` is added by default to the `RestTemplate` converters.

So, to have deserialization take place, I could use two ways:

- remove the `StringHttpMessageConverter` from the RestTemplate's converters.
- use a dummy 'holder' class with the correct `@JsonCreator` method

  ```
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public class StringHolder {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String value;

    @JsonCreator
    public static StringHolder create(String value){
      return new StringHolder(value);
    }
  }
  ```

  Now, `template.postForObject("http://...", request, StringHolder.class).getValue()` is returning the escaped String.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the restfull returned me a JSON matrix so I found a page that converts the JSON into pojos this was what I return

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

```html
// MyPojo

public class MyPojo
{
    private Items[] items;

    private First first;

    public Items[] getItems ()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems (Items[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public First getFirst ()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst (First first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [items = "+items+", first = "+first+"]";
    }
}

// CLASE DE FIRST

public class First
{
    private String $ref;

    public String get$ref ()
    {
        return $ref;
    }

    public void set$ref (String $ref)
    {
        this.$ref = $ref;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [$ref = "+$ref+"]";
    }
}


// CLASE ITEM

public class Items
{
    private String nombre_inmueble;

    private String inmueble_id;

    public String getNombre_inmueble ()
    {
        return nombre_inmueble;
    }

    public void setNombre_inmueble (String nombre_inmueble)
    {
        this.nombre_inmueble = nombre_inmueble;
    }

    public String getInmueble_id ()
    {
        return inmueble_id;
    }

    public void setInmueble_id (String inmueble_id)
    {
        this.inmueble_id = inmueble_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [nombre_inmueble = "+nombre_inmueble+", inmueble_id = "+inmueble_id+"]";
    }
}


// CLASE PRINCIPAL

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApeplazasDropDownApplication {

 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApeplazasDropDownApplication.class);
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  final String urlGETList = "http://localhost/test/getAll";
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  
  
  MyPojo quote = restTemplate.getForObject(urlGETList, MyPojo.class);
     log.info(quote.getItems()[1].getInmueble_id());
 
  
         
        }
        
  
  
 }

// MY API

{
  
  "items": [
 
             {
 "inmueble_id": 48,

               "nombre_inmueble": "ACAPULCO"
 
             },
 
             {
 "inmueble_id": 33,

             "nombre_inmueble": "MONTERREY"

             },
   ],
   "first": 
          {

   "$ref": "https://localhost/test/getAll"

          }

}
```